# Is there any reason why I have to enter the SSL certificate password twice at a ProFTPD restart?

Tags: ssl, ftp

I'm using the Ubuntu 10.4 build in ProFTPD and don't understand why I have to "verify" the password I enter as it's checked immediately. (This reminds me on entering Wifi passwords twice in Windows where it's also nonsense.)

Prompt message:

```
ftpadmin@ftp:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/proftpd restart
  * Stopping ftp server proftpd                                           [ OK ] 
  * Starting ftp server proftpd                                                  
Please provide passphrases for these encrypted certificate keys:
RSA key for the x.x.x.x#21 (ftp.foo.bar) server: 
Verifying - RSA key for the x.x.x.x#21 (ftp.foo.bar) server: 
                                                                          [ OK ]
```

TLS config:

```
<IfModule mod_tls.c>
 TLSEngine                   on
 TLSLog                      /var/log/proftpd/tls.log
 TLSProtocol                 SSLv23
 TLSRSACertificateFile       /etc/ssl/private/server.crt
 TLSRSACertificateKeyFile    /etc/ssl/private/server.key
 TLSOptions                  AllowClientRenegotiations NoCertRequest EnableDiags 
 TLSVerifyClient             off
</IfModule>
```

Comment: SSL? Please give us the prompt message?

Comment: @quanta - I updated my question.

Comment: and the options related to `TLS` in your `proftpd.conf`?

Comment: @quanta - again I updated the question - Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a challenge password on both the crt and the key?  I don't think it remembers the password and tries to apply it to the second file.

Comment: @polynomial Can a certificate be password protected? It's clear that the private key is, but the certificate? Furthermore I don't believe it's the case as ProFTPd is explicitly asking for a "verification" of the password. I guess I should ask the people who make ProFTPd.

Answer (score 0):

```
TLSRSACertificateKeyFile    /etc/ssl/private/server.key
```

You get this dialog because the RSA private key inside your `server.key` is stored in encrypted format. You need a passphrase to parse this file.

You can remove the encryption from the RSA private key with:

```
cd /etc/ssl/private/
mv server.key server.key.bak
openssl rsa -in server.key.bak -out server.key
chmod 400 server.key
```

Now `server.key` will contain an uncrypted copy of the key, point `TLSRSACertificateKeyFile` to this file, it will not prompt you for a passphrase.

But, NOTICE that, if anyone gets this key, they will be able to impersonate you.

Comment: I'm aware that it's encrypted. My question is why I have to enter it TWICE? Once should be enough, not?